# Custom scripts to checkout TFS

Tags: tfs, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

We have a team city hosted on Linux OS machine. We have a TFS repository for which we need to make auto build and  auto deploy. But when I am setting up VCS root it giving me error that TFS root can be created only on a machine running under Windows machine. I looked for the solution and one solution I got is we can use tfs-plugins. 

Is there a way to write a custom script must be used to checkout the code for every checkin. Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current limitation of Teamcity 9.x.

TFS does have a *[Cross-Platform Command Line Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx)*, and the better news is that Teamcity 10.x (currently under development) will have *[Cross-Platform TFS Integration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Team+Foundation+Server)*

**Workaround**

Your TFS cross platform utility will still work on Unix without Teamcity 9.x recognizing it.

For now, ignore the *Version Control Settings* of your *Build Configuration*, and as your first build step use the command line runner to invoke the TFS command line utility and checkout your files to your working directory.

You may even be able to add other build steps that allow you to label your changeset base on successful builds and so on.